# Removing attributes from an activerecord got via .includes

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am having a really weird problem while attempting to do a very simple thing. I am doing an .includes on a model to get a row of data from the database. On the return object I need to remove certain attributes conditionally. And the final aim is to reinsert this row as a new record based on the changes I make on the attributes using my conditions.

```
def myUpdate

  dbObj = Obj.includes(:name,
                       :addr1,
                       :addr2,
                       :state,
                       :description).find(params[:id])

  #dbObjective.attributes().except('description')
  #dbObjective.description = nil
  #dbObjective.attributes().delete('description')
  # After setting more attributes, persist this object
end
```

I tried all possibilities that I could think of, but the attribute is just not getting removed. What am I missing? I am on Ruby on Rails 4.2.

Comment: Are you certain you understand how [`includes`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes) and [`attributes`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/attributes) work? `includes` is an association query method and does not seem like what you are using it for and `attributes` is not modifiable in this fashion as it is a `dup` of the actual attributes

Comment: is `Obj.includes(...)` like associations? I just see a find & I am not sure what you are trying to do

Comment: I apologise, I totally messed up the code I was posting in the question. It was a find and not includes, sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0):

`includes` is used to include associated tables in your query for `join` queries and eager loading, not for table attributes. You do not need to do anything special to access an object's attributes.

`attributes` returns a `Hash` instance containing the record's attributes as key-value pairs, and operating on it will change only the `Hash` instance itself, not the record.

There are several ways to update attributes. One of the easiest ways is using the built in `setter` methods given to you by `ActiveRecord`. If you really want to change attributes using the `Hash` API you can store the `attributes` hash in a variable, manipulate the hash, and pass it as an argument to `update`, which accepts an attributes hash as it's argument.

### Using `setter` methods

```
def myUpdate

  dbObj = Obj.find(params[:id])

  dbObj.description = 'new_description'
  dbObj.name = 'new_name
  dbObj.save
end
```

### Using `update`

```
def myUpdate

  dbObj = Obj.find(params[:id])

  attributes = dbObj.attributes # This is how you would update the object by manipulating the attributes hash
  attributes.delete(:description) # this will NOT end up changing the attribute in the DB
  attributes[:name] = nil # this will successfully set name to NULL in the DB
  dbObj.update(attributes) # pass the manipulated hash to the `update` method to persist the changes
end
```

`delete`ing fields from the hash will not have an effect on the persisted object. `update` only performs an insert on fields present in the hash that have changed.

Comment: Thank you, you righted my poorly asked question and answered it. If I may, can I ask you some follow up questions. 1. After changing an attribute the save is not automatically triggered right? 2. Say I did use an includes using as association and on that I did an attribute set, would that trigger an update on the db? I am not sure as to when the db update gets triggered in the case of ar query methods